# security issue with openfire send http request (file_get_contents() PHP function)

Tags: php, httprequest, openfire

I have some example sending request with file_get_contents() function from PHP to openfire API. Request is like:

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost:9090/plugin/userService/userservice/?type=add&secret=secret_key&username=username&password=password");
```

This type of request stores user data into database.

If there's any possible for hacker (user) to hack or track this request and get secret key and password?

I know for better type of sending request but I'm interested if there's a way to hack it.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course there is, you're sending the request as a plaintext request (not using SSL) so any man-in-the-middle attack can read your secret

Comment: But how? Can you explain me the way how to do it?

Comment: If you're actually using `localhost` you're safe since the entire transfer takes place inside one machine. If you're using any other address you should be using SSL, without which anyone can read what you're sending.

Comment: Try using a packet sniffer when you make the request (eg wireshark), and it will show the requested URL with all its arguments as readable text

Comment: If API server works only with localhost - no. As long as localhost does not have anything 'bad' installed, but than it would not actually matter )

Comment: Yes. I'm using localhost because each of these applications runs on one server.

Comment: But I'm wondering why openfire make this like that. When you send the request this is the way to do it. This is big issue with security.